# Close bootstrap modal with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have a placed  iframe with some contents in a website. On clicking the elements i am opening a boostrap modal. A stylesheet is defined for website where styles are applied directly to html elements without using classes. Modal is having separate stylesheet. Now my modal styles are overridden by website styles.

How can I remove styles applied by website stylesheet on my modal. I googled a lot but i couldn't find any solution. I am struck with that issue.

Comment: Create a JSFiddle with your codes. Would be easy to answer

Comment: How about `document.getElementById('your_id').removeAttribute('style')`

Comment: If i remove style attribute inline styles are cleared not styles applied by stylesheet

Comment: @user2083041 did you try my code, It will remove the all the styles of modal like dark background, blocked scroll etc.

Comment: How about this `$('link[title=titleName]').prop('disabled',true);`

Comment: You can remove the style-sheet with this.

Comment: I already tried to disable stylesheet. If i disable a  stylesheet it is not available to entire website. I shoould disable stylesheet only for modal not for complete website

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code

```
    <a href='#' onclick='closeModel()'>Model</a>
    <script>        
        function closeModel(){
            $('#modelid').modal('hide');
            $('#modelid').removeClass('className');
            $('#modelid').addClass('className');
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: styles are applied directly to elements not based on class  or id

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
$('#your_modal_ID').modal('hide');
$('body').removeClass('modal-open');
$('.modal-backdrop').remove();
```

Comment: It will remove properties/styles of modal. I need to stop or disable the styles applied to elements inside the modal from website stylesheet